# jQuery dialog loses all features when loading a view with more jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, dialog

I am working with an MVC 4 project that contains some jQuery functionality. The problem I am running into is that in one of my views, I have a `TimeSheet` table, followed by a button that says "Add New" which triggers a jQuery dialog box. In the box, I load another view that allows the user to input information regarding a new `TimeSheet` entry, featuring other jQuery widgets such as autocomplete, datepicker, and spinner.

The dialog view loads fine, and works exactly the way I want it to. Now, the issue is that once the view has loaded within the dialog box, all dialog functionality goes out the window. No matter how I define the dialog box in my original View, it's features do not work.

For example, the dialog will not be draggable if I set it to be, `closeOnEscape` will not work even if set to true, and what annoys me most is that the close button (x) in the top right corner does not work, and has left me with no way to close the dialog... Someone please help :(

Here is the relevant code:

**Button and Script from TimeSheet View:**

```
<button id="AddNew_1">Add New</button>

@section scripts{
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {      

            $("#AddNew_1").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 570,
                width: 930,
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).load("@Url.Action("New", "Task")", function()
                    {                       
                        $("#dialog").find("script").each(function(i) { 
                            eval($(this).text());
                        });
                    }); 
                }                 
            });   
        });

    </script>
    }

    <div id="dialog" title="Add New" style="overflow: hidden"></div>
```

**Dialog View:**

```
@model timeSheetSystems.Models.OperationModels

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddNew";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/View1.cshtml";
Model.Date = DateTime.Today;
}

@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>Add New TimeSheet Entry</h1>
            <h2></h2>
        </hgroup>                
    </div>
</section>
}

@section scripts{

<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-         ui.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/code_jquery_com-ui-1_10_3-jquery--ui.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.mousewheel.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/demos/external/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/demos/external/globalize.culture.de-DE.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/demos/external/globalize.culture.ja-JP.js"></script>

<style>
.ui-widget {
font-size: 1em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
font-size: 1em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
.ui-autocomplete {
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
* html .ui-autocomplete {
height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">    //autocomplete


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#AC").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({

                url: "/Task/AutoComplete", type: "POST", datatype: "json",
                data: { q: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.SPTaskId + ", " + item.TaskName + ", " +     item.Application, value: item.TaskId };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#TaskId").val(ui.item.value);
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        }
    });
});



</script>

<script type="text/javascript">    //spinner
$(function () {
    $("#WorkedHours").spinner({
        step: 0.50,
        numberFormat: "n",
        min: 0
    });
    $("#culture").change(function () {
        var current = $("#spinner").spinner("value");
        Globalize.culture($(this).val());
        $("#spinner").spinner("value", current);
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">    //calendar
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Date").datepicker();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ui-icon ui-icon-closethick").click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog("close");
});
</script>


}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" id="culture" value="en-EN" />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskId, "Task")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" id="AC"/>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskId, new { id = "TaskId" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, "Operation Description")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { rows = 5, cols = 200 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkedHours, "Hours Worked")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WorkedHours)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkedHours)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have included your jquery and jqueryUI script the Dialog view in the `@section scripts{}` section. This Dialoge view is loaded via ajax and the scripts included in it are not accessible by the main view.

Try moving these scripts to the Layout or the parent view with loads the Dialog view. I am sure this will solve the unusual behavior your are facing.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the scripts inside of the Dialog view are not my concern. The scripts inside of the Main View which initialize the dialog box and it's features is my concern. I cannot close the dialog box in the Main View once the Dialog View has been loaded inside of the box.